# AWS API gateway cache - invalidate cache for all users of a tenant

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, microservices, aws-api-gateway, multi-tenant

I have a resource called Sites.

I am planning to have an endpoint as follows:

```
/tenant/:tenantId/users/:userId/sites/:siteId
```

The endpoint is to return a site’s tree which will vary based on the tenantId, userId, siteId.

**The sites tree returned by this endpoint will also change based on updates in another resource (i.e users/groups)**

How should the cache be discarded for all users of a given tenant whenever there is a change in the site's resource itself or when there is a change in groups?

I understand the client cache-control headers can be used but just not sure how they could be used in this situation? I am also aware of the stage cache purge but I do not need to do it for all tenants in this situation so not too keen on it.

Comment: you can use event streaming like kafka,rbbitMQ,SQS here. Once change happens in other entities, publish the message, after that consumer will listen to that message and discard/purge the old data.

Comment: @Vaibs I understand use of the events but how can we use them with API gateway selective cache purge

Comment: not sure, it is the best idea, but you can use lambda which listens to the event and calls explicitly to the rest point with Cache-Control: max-age=0 header. So this will invalidate the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Following Approach can be followed.

**Token Storage & Validation**

- Maintain token list in table auth-details-> id,token,user_id,tenant_id
- Maintain token in cache with time-to-live
- While processing request validate Token against both auth-details table from step and token validation API

**Invalidating Token from cache**

Use AmazonMQ, and define publisher to publish message when invalidate condition meets. Define consumer which will be responsible for purging cache for a particular tenant. Use @CacheEvict annotation to clear data for particular tenant.

```
@CacheEvict(value = "your-cache-name", key = "#tenantId + '_details'")
  public Long deleteCacheForTenant(Long tenantId) {
    return tenantId;
  }
```